# Read/Write files on Windows Phone 8 via PC USB connection

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I'm attempting to write a music player for Windows Phone 8 because the current XBox Music app is very lacking. Basically I'd like to be able to sync files on the device based on whether they've been rated up or down.

Since the device itself won't let me delete or make changes to the music files on the app, I'm thinking of keeping a database of ratings in isolated storage where I can write data. Then I'll have a companion app on a PC read this database from the device, and then remove the files that have been rated downwards.

Unfortunately I am completely unable to access the device on my PC through code. I know it's possible since I can access the device through Windows Explorer, but when I load up some C# code to try to read the files, it simply cannot find the device at all. I've used the File Picker to see if I can modify files, but every time I select a file, Windows copies the file from the device into a temporary directory on C:\, so when I try deleting it, it just deletes the temporary file and the file remains on the device.

What in the heck is going on here? I cannot seem to find any information about accessing a WP8 in code over USB. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The Windows Phone Power Tools on Codeplex can write files to isolated storage from a PC connection - you might want to check out its source code: https://wptools.codeplex.com/

Comment: This is totally wrong - and this answer made us lose 2-3 weeks worth of coding because we were not careful. Windows phone power tools is a developer tool - this means it will only work if the PC has Visual studio installed. It is not created to be run by consumers. Looking at its source code misleads you to use Connectivity API which later on turns out to be not usable closer to the release. If you would like to transfer files/music - I would recommend you to look at MTP (Media Transfer Protocol)